# onblur event not working when open with Android browser

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, dom-events, onblur

Everything is working when open it with Opera mobile and Firefox, but when I open it with Android browser, the function not working. How to fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('harga')[0];
var tax = document.getElementsByClassName('dp_per')[0];
var taxAmount = document.getElementsByClassName('dp')[0];

tax.onblur = function() {
    taxAmount.value = parseFloat(price.value) * parseFloat(tax.value) / 100;
}
})(jQuery);
```

Here is what I've made:
http://jsfiddle.net/mYEUP/

Comment: Since `dp_per` is a select element, wouldn't it make more sense to use the `onchange` event?

Comment: when i use onchange, this event not working at all :(
but I've found the solution using if-else hehe :)

Comment: If `onchange` doesn't work, then you are doing somethignwrong, that you aren't showing here. And I don't see how "if/else" would help in this case...

Comment: yeah I was trying to figure it out, but my time is running out to complete this project, so I leave it and still using my own solution, there are another math process below it, but I can't show it right here.
btw, thanks for your help :)